# Events not firing Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a top level controller as follows

```
.controller('body', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading, SQL) {
$ionicLoading.show({
    template: 'Initializing...'
});

$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    console.log('platform Ready!');

    SQL.Init().then(function () {
        console.log('DB Ready!');
        $scope.initialized = true;
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

    document.addEventListener("online", function () { console.log("online"); }, false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", function () { console.log("offline"); }, false);
});
```

})

The problem I am having is that the online and offline events are not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the network-information plugin? http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.network-information

Comment: Yes I have and I confirmed it works by manually requesting network status. It's event stuff that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: If you try the same code in a vanilla Cordova project, inside the deviceready handler, is it working ok? You do see other console messages, right?

Comment: $cordovaNetwork still does not trigger those documented events

Comment: You didn't answer the second part though - if you try outside of Ionic is it working? How are you testing status - by enabling airplane mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ngCordova network layer, it does this work for you http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Network

Comment: I don't want to manually check for the network. I want the framework detect when network goes on and off and do something with that info. Is that possible with ngCordova network?

Comment: It doesn't but You can bind $cordovaNetwork.isOffline() to a scope variable and then let Angularjs check everytime for you.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example? I am having a brain fart on how it would work without any action from the user.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working. Are you trying on a mobile device or with ionic serve????

Comment: Android device. HTC one and a Samsung tablet.  The code above works 1/10 times, only for one of the events, very unreliable. I amausing airplane mode to stimulate no service.